# I am getting 401 ssl required error for likedin rest api while accessing some basic profile fields

Tags: api, rest, ssl, linkedin-api, user-profile

I am using rest api to fetch basic profile data from linkedin with php code. I am successfully able to generate access code and access token but I am getting ssl required error whenever I tried to get basic profile using following url 
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json

I followed all steps to make authenticated requests as listed there https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

I am using a non ssl url as call back parameter , Is it necessary to use ssl url ? If not then why I am getting this error .
looking for a solution

below is code to get profile fields

```
$host = "api.linkedin.com";
$path = "/v1/people/~)";
//$arr = array('oauth2_access_token' => $access['access_token']);
$token = $access['access_token'];

  $header[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";


$ch = curl_init();

// endpoint url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host . $path);

// set request as regular post
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

// set http version
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 'HTTP/1.1');

// set data to be send
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($arr));

// set header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

// set header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);

// return transfer as string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_export($response);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution was to use https:// instead of just http://